Adding asp-for tag to the input disables my css
So I have already made the design prior to adding the OnPostAsync and the asp-for tag.
so the image below is the design:
Image of Register Page before adding asp-for tag
So now after I added the asp-for tag to the inputs, this happened:
Image of Register Page after adding asp-for tag
<section class="bod">
    <div class="container">
        <form class="reg-form" method="post">
            <div class="user-Details">
                <a href="/LoginPage">@* <img class="back" src="/Images/back.png"/> *@ Back</a>
                <h3>User Registration</h3>
                <hr class="divide"/>
                
                <div class="input-container">
                    <input type="text" class="inp" id="Username" name="Username" asp-for="Username" />
                    <label for="Username" class="lbl">Username</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="input-container">
                    <input type="email" class="inp" id="email" asp-for="Email" />
                    <label for="email" class="lbl">Email</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="input-container">
                    <input type="password" class="inp" id="password" asp-for="Password" />
                    <label for="password" class="lbl">Password</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <button class="btn-reg" type="submit">Register</button>

                
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>

Above is my code for the html
and this is for my css:
.user-Details {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 50%);
    align-items: center;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.input-container {
    position: relative; /* To position the label relative to this container */
    margin-bottom: 30px; /* Add spacing between inputs */
    width: 100%; /* Ensure input box and label are aligned */
}

.inp {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%; /* Match container width */
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 10px;
}

.lbl {
    position: absolute; /* Allow precise positioning */
    bottom: -28px; /* Move the label below the input box */
    left: 10px; /* Align with input padding */
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px; /* Optional smaller size */
    color: #333; /* Optional color */
}

.btn-reg {
    width: 80%;
    height: 35px;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #90D5FF;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

I tried changing to Id, but still it doesn't work and now I don't know what to do. I just need the design to retain after using asp-for tag

Have you examined what the renderer html looks like?  Look at that via View Source in your browser.

I tried looking at it and after looking the  , in the element it says
̶b̶u̶t̶t̶o̶n̶, input {overflow: visible}, does this affect the design?
